# Joomla Newsletter component

Tags: joomla, components, newsletter, subscriber

Is there a joomla newsletter component to create and send letters to some joomla group members (group should be selectable)? Please keep in mind that users do not signed up for newsletter subscription. Instead, they agree our general terms which includes terms about letters on signup. If we use any traditional newsletter component we face the problem that there are no records of subscribers in the component.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this one. 
http://codingmall.com/products-mainmenu-8/158-newsletter-for-jomsocial
As mentioned here, you can send letters to different joomla groups.

The other option is to import list of users if you already have a newsletter component. But that requires some coding skills.

Comment: You do realize that this is for JomSocial which is another extensions and a very expensive one at that.

Comment: Hi @Lodder. The OP didn't insist the solution had to be free so this answer seems valid or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this in AcyMailing Enterprise version.

**Reference:**
http://www.acyba.com/forum/5-how-to/31763-register-joomla-users-into-acymailing-based-on-groups.html?format=html&lang=en#31774